# grep the ps output to find processes running on a certain user

Tags: process, grep, command-line-interface, ps

I am working through some metasploit lessons and I have a meterpreter session open to a Windows victim machine. If I run `ps`, I see a list of processes, some running as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM[image: processes]

So I want to filter this process list to see only those running as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`. But if I try `ps -ef | grep -i "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"` I don't get any results. (same for trying to do "NT", "\SYSTEM", etc)

[image: no results]

If I search for a process name, like "spool" for example, I do get results:
[image]

So how can I `grep` the `ps` output to filter by the username?

Comment: Please replace all images with its text. See: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

`\S` in `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` is interpreted as an escaped `S` (Ie. the backslash is removed). Add `-F` for "fixed string" to search for a literal string, or preserve the backslash by escaping it:

```
grep -Fi 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' # or
grep -i 'NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM'
```

Comment: you are right on the escaped S point, but why did I also not get any results when I was grep-ing for "nt" or "system"?